# Could not find lvl License.apk

Tags: android, android-lvl

I am getting this error message when I try to run my app that has the lvl installed as a library.

I followed the steps outlined on the developer.android.com site for installing the lvl library:

I copied the "market_licensing" folder into my project folder,

I created a new library called "License" with "new", "android project using Motodev     studio", "create project from existing source", "SDK Target" API-7.

I set the main project "project","properties", "android", "add library" to "License", and checked "IsLibrary".

Still, the lvl library doesn't seem to build with the main application, giving me this error.

Answer (score 3):

I decided to give up on using the library concept to incorporate lvl after trying for 8 hours. The Eclipse/android environment is still too buggy to work with libraries.

The developer.android.com site provided an alternate (and much better) way to include the lvl code:

"As an alternative to adding the LVL as a library project, you can copy the library sources directly into your application. To do so, copy (or import) the LVL's library/src/com directory into your application's src/ directory."

I did this, and it works! Stay away from the use of libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse IDE is buggy with this library paths.But I managed to get rid of it

1. First copy the LVL Library to the folder just at the same directory your project is located. This will make relative path simple e.g. '../library' instead of long path which make it buggy and Then try Import in eclipse

2.Add Library in the way described same in documentation

http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html

3.Remove Library Project from your Build Path. This library.apk not found error is just because you may have clicked on fix projected 'Add to Build Path' while removing error and adding library.